# Fastest way to recover the return value of a function passed to multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a heavy batch work so I sliced it into 30(number of my CPUs) mini batch and I made 30 `multiprocessing.Process` to do them(For some reason I did not use `multiprocessing.Pool`). For the return value, I have used 30 `multiprocessing.Queue`. It is an overview of my code:

```
    def minibatch(q, data, i):
        do_some_work_data_i
        q.put(return_value)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        q1 = Queue()
        p1 = Process(target=minibatch, args=(q1, data[1], 1))
        p1.start()

        q2 = Queue()
        p2 = Process(target=minibatch, args=(q2, data[2], 2))
        p2.start()

        first_return_value = q1.get()
        second_return_value = q2.get()

        p1.join()
        p2.join()
```

Now, I found that it is too much slow! if each mini-batch takes 10 seconds, I expect that my code takes around 10 seconds to run but it takes much more. So what should I do instead?

Comment: You should indeed try using Pool.map()

Comment: Why is get called before join?

Comment: @soroush From the look of the pseudocode, there isn't anything wrong. Your problem probably lies elsewhere, like in do_some_work_data_i

Comment: From the look of your pseudocode, your gets and joins are the exact same bottleneck, so I guess it doesn't matter that you get before joining

Comment: @Mars I copied this template from another site. It works properly. Isn't it correct?

Comment: Are you sure you really have 30 physical cores? That seems like a wired number

Comment: Yeah, its fine. Here, get means "Wait here until this value is available" and join means "wait here until the job is done," which mean the same thing in this case. But since you consider the return value as a return value, it feels weird reading the code, thats all

Comment: @Mars I have changed the orders but no improvement.

Comment: Yeah, it won't be an improvement. They're waiting for the same thing! Your problem is in do_some_work_data_i

Comment: Add a start and finish time print function to your process handler and you'll see where your problem is!

Comment: @Mars when I do not use multiprocessing, the function do_some_work_data works properly and fast. I think the problem is with copying data for each process but the data is not too big.

Comment: If you run sequentially, how long does everything take? When you run it in parallel, how long does it take?

Comment: @Mars I did what you said with some small data and I run it for 30 iterations. multiprocessing with 2 process takes 95 seconds and without multiprocessing it takes less than one second.

Comment: Even more of an indicator that the error is in the processing part!

Comment: @Mars what does it mean? I didn't change any functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182404/discussion-between-soroush-and-mars).

Comment: Finally, I found that making a separate process with 'multiprocessing.Process' is my bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtime sequential

```
processing time * number of runs
```

Runtime parallel

```
(processing time) * (number of runs / number of parallel processes) 
+ (process start overhead * number parallel processes)
```

If your processing time isn't long to begin with, then the overhead of making new processes will outweighs the savings you get from parallelism.

If your sequential batch takes ~300 seconds, then your parallel implementation will probably only take <11 seconds, but if your sequential batch only takes 10 seconds, then running it on 30 processes may actually take longer.

Comment: yes, the bottleneck is 'process start overhead'. And I'm surprised because it's really slow!

Comment: My tests put it at about 0.16 seconds per process on Windows, but Linux is supposed to be faster!